# Terraform getting UnsupportedOperation: Microsoft SQL when trying to start an amazon-linux instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-linux

I'm trying to start an instance on aws using terraform and using the amazon-linux-2 image. But I'm getting an Erro for Microsoft SQL Server Entreprise Edition.

```
provider "aws" {
    version = "~> 2.0"
    region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "dev" {
  ami = "${data.aws_ami.amazon-linux-2.id}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "terraform"
  tags = {
    "Name" = "dev-terraform"
  }
}

data "aws_ami" "amazon-linux-2" {
  most_recent = true
  owners = ["amazon"]

  filter {
    name   = "owner-alias"
    values = ["amazon"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["amzn2-ami-hvm*"]
   }
  filter {
    name   = "architecture"
    values = ["x86_64"]
  }
}
```

The error:

```
Error: Error launching source instance: UnsupportedOperation: Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition is not supported for the instance type 't2.micro'.
        status code: 400, request id: 72df60b9-46ac-4616-ab3f-b964ab2f3156

  on main.tf line 6, in resource "aws_instance" "dev":
   6: resource "aws_instance" "dev" {
```

I'm not having any relation with Microsoft and I cannot understanding why this error is appearing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is correct. Your data source query returns:

```
amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20190313-x86_64-gp2-SQL_2017_Enterprise-2021.02.25
```

Please use the following data source instead:

```
data "aws_ami" "latest_amazon_2" {
  most_recent = true
  owners      = ["amazon"]
  name_regex = "^amzn2-ami-hvm-.*x86_64-gp2$"
}
```

Comment: Just getting the same error. My code looks like this now:
`
provider "aws" {
    version = "~> 2.0"
    region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "dev" {
  ami = "${data.aws_ami.latest_amazon_2.id}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "terraform-dati"
  tags = {
    "Name" = "dev-terraform"
  }
}

data "aws_ami" "latest_amazon_2" {
  most_recent = true
  owners = ["amazon"]
  name_regex = "^amzn2-ami-hvm-.*x86_64-gp2"
}
`

Comment: @ArthurÁvila Wow. You are correct. The data source I gave is what I personally use, and I see now that it stopped working. Please give me a moment to check what's happening.

Comment: @ArthurÁvila Sorry for the wait. I updated the `name_regex`.

Comment: awesome mate! Just worked fine! Thanks for that!!

Comment: @ArthurÁvila No problem. Glad it worked out :-)